# Insert frame in between frames in flash CS5

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

Context : 
I have to modify an existing banner which contains lot of pictures and texts. Now I need to insert some pictures and text in between the flash file. For example, I need to insert a picture at frame 500 which have length of 100 frames. So how can I move the 100 frames to the right ?

How to insert a new layer and its key frames in between existing frames in Adobe Flash CS5.
I have the following Scene, [image]

I need to get the following 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

F5 to insert a new keyframe, and F6 to convert that to a new frame.

Answer (score 0):

click on the layer name and drag to between of layers

Comment: It does not give the expected result. The output will remain same.

Answer (score 0):

your output depend on your frame not your layer
you most remove the keyframe of layer 3 ( 10 to 20 )
and add 10 frame to layer 2